# Techniques for sharing definitions in XSD?

Tags: xml, dictionary, xsd, xml-validation

We are building enterprise wide XML Schemas.  There are common elements between schemas that are built by different teams we would like all of them to same names for the same data elements so is there is there a way for them to use the same data dictionary.

We would overtime add elements to the data dictionary as we build out schemas but do want all of them to use the same names 
for example `customerfirstname` should be same in all the different schemas how do we achieve this?

Comment: Since a schema can include another schema file, you could have a common xsd that each team's schemas include.

Answer (score 0):

You achieve separation between shared and unshared control of vocabularies in XSD through ***namespaces***.

**Group 1 (and other groups) can define an XSD in a namespace they control,**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:g1="http://example.com/group1"
           xmlns:c1="http://example.com/common"
           targetNamespace="http://example.com/group1">

  <xs:import namespace="http://example.com/common" schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="Group1X">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="g1:Group1Y"/>
        <xs:element ref="c1:Common1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Group1Y" type="xs:string"/>

</xs:schema>
```

**and import an XSD in a namespace under common, shared control:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://example.com/common">

  <xs:element name="Common1" type="xs:string"/>

</xs:schema>
```

**so that both can be used in the same XML document**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<g1:Group1X xmlns:g1="http://example.com/group1"
            xmlns:c1="http://example.com/common"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/group1 group1.xsd">
  <g1:Group1Y>
    Vocabulary in the "http://example.com/group1" namespace is under
    the control of group 1.
  </g1:Group1Y>
  <c1:Common1>
    Vocabulary in the "http://example.com/common" namespace is under
    common control.
  </c1:Common1>
</g1:Group1X>
```

**without conflict, as requested.**